# Problema con consulta joins en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola a todos estoy trando de hacer una consulta en laravel usando query builder pero al momento de obtener el resultado me sale mensaje de error y en la bd mysql de mi local host arme la sentencia y ahi si me devuelve datos correctamente. Como podria arreglar mi sentencia para que funcione en laravel?

Dejo codigo que uso en mi controller

```
$activities = DB::table('orders')
                    ->select(DB::raw("count(*) as cantidad, projects.name as proyecto, orders.cod_document as orden, activity_project.status as estado"))
                    ->join('projects','projects.id','=','orders.id')
                    ->join('activity_project','activity_project.project_id','=','projects.id')                    
                    ->where('activity_project.status', 'Completada')
                    ->groupBy('projects.name, orders.cod_document, activity_project.status')
                    ->orderBy('orders.cod_document')
                    ->get();
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `groupBy` no espera que le pases un string con varios campos como estás haciendo

```
 ->groupBy('projects.name, orders.cod_document, activity_project.status')
```

Lo que espera, en cambio, es que le pases un campo por parámetro:

```
->groupBy(
     'projects.name', 
     'orders.cod_document', 
     'activity_project.status'
 )
```

O un solo parámetro con un array de campos

```
->groupBy([
     'projects.name', 
     'orders.cod_document', 
     'activity_project.status'
 ])
```

También podrías pasarle ese string al método `groupByRaw`

```
 ->groupByRaw('projects.name, orders.cod_document, activity_project.status')
```

Pero me parece no es necesario para tu caso de uso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema era el group by, consulta para que se usa el raw?

Comment: Con el raw podrías hacer `groupByRaw('CONCAT_WS('_', projects.name, MONTH(orders.created_at)')`